# How to solve "Failed to traverse parents of commit"?

Tags: git, github

I wanna push my repo to GitHub. I committed my changes, and then used the `git status` command per [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/git-push-pull). This is the response I got:

```
error: Could not read 2e647eb0498a87d6d9c54eb9efd78f29d24f6da8
error: Could not read 2e647eb0498a87d6d9c54eb9efd78f29d24f6da8
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 92dfb5485cf2e5021dd979db8f96eaac5e3f181a
On branch main
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's something wrong with your repository (locally, on your computer: it's damaged). How this came about is not clear, although in my experience, it usually happens because someone stored their Git repository in a Dropbox or iCloud folder.

Comment: I'm storing the repo locally.

Comment: Drobox and iCloud *are* local, they're just messed-with by Dropbox and iCloud (consequently breaking Git). But if it's not one of those, it's something else...

Answer (score -3):

Maybe a failure of your local drive? Check the S.M.A.R.T. status of your hard disk drive (and maybe run some additional S.M.A.R.T. self tests), - and in any case, first make sure you have backups of all your data!